# How is it possible that class is implementing only methods(protocol) that it needs?

Tags: swift

I got a code where the specific class is implementing the protocol, the protocol has (ex: 3 methods), but the class is implementing only one of them.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
 func a()
 func b()
 func c()
}

class Foo: MyProtocol {
 func a() { ... }
}
```

and this works, but magic is if I add a new method in the protocol `eg: func d()`, I got an error that class `Foo` doesn't implement all methods of the protocol.

What is a diff between my new method `func d()` and others that class `Foo` also doesn't implement? But on my method, I got an error, and on others no...

Comment: The protocol has an extension with default implementations of the methods.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means `b()` and `c()` have default implementations. If you search for `extension MyProtocol` in the codebase you should be able to find their default implementations.